# Where can i download the the geopandas .whl file?

Tags: python, windows, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas library without having to use `pip install geopandas` (admin constraints).

My work around is to download the binaries and install this way. I can't find the geopandas windows binary, but I've been able to locate the other dependencies.

I am looking on [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#jpype](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#jpype)

Could someone please point me in the right site?

Comment: I guessing you have to clone the repo and use the source code then: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas . But because it relies on other dependencies you would have to do that as well and so on... better ask your admin to give you the rights

Comment: Go to the package's page on PyPI (for example, https://pypi.org/project/geopandas), click on the Download Files button near the top on the left (for example, https://pypi.org/project/geopandas/#files), and if wheels are available, download them from there. Some packages may not be available as wheels, so you'll need to download the source and build them, if necessary.

Comment: The site you're using now is no longer up to date, so I wouldn't use it for the latest versions.

Comment: You don't need admin privileges to use `pip`, unless you need system-wide installation (this requires sudo/root). Also, you can set up virtual environment and install any packages there without sudo.